# How to change default HTML template in Vaadin

Tags: java, html, maven, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin with maven application. What I want is changing the default html template. 
When I run the application, the generated HTML looks like this :

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10;chrome=1">
<style type="text/css">html, body {height:100%;margin:0;}</style>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="./VAADIN/themes/customBootstrap/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="./VAADIN/themes/customBootstrap/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./VAADIN/themes/customBootstrap/styles.css"><script type="text/javascript"
...
```

I want to change the "meta" properties, add "link" and also add some other components like :

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Is there a way to do that with Vaadin ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom servlet that extend the VaadinServlet:

```
public class BootstrapServlet extends VaadinServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
    super.servletInitialized();
    getService().addSessionInitListener(new SessionInitListener() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void sessionInit(SessionInitEvent event) {
            event.getSession().addBootstrapListener( new BootstrapListener() {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void modifyBootstrapFragment(
                        BootstrapFragmentResponse response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void modifyBootstrapPage(BootstrapPageResponse response) {


                    if(response.getRequest().getHeader("User-Agent").contains("MSIE 8.0")){

                        response.getDocument().head().appendElement("script").attr("type", "text/javascript").attr("src", "https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js");
                        response.getDocument().head().appendElement("script").attr("type", "text/javascript").attr("src", "https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js");

                    }
                }}
            );
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Then change the default servlet in your web.xml from

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>myappname</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
...
```

To

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>myappnam</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>your.package.name.BootstrapServlet</servlet-class>
...
```

This will not add the

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
```

however it will conditionally add the scripts based on whether or not the UserAgent is IE 8 or not.

FYI, I am actually trying to do the exact same thing because I am using twitters Bootstrap,  media queries, in my project. Whether or not those scripts work along side Vaadin 7 is yet to be seen.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `@Theme("yourtheme")` annotation? - [Vaadin Themes](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html)
It is really simple, you just have to copy your new theme into the `WEB-INF/VAADIN` directory.

Also you can add custom javascripts to your metadata with `@JavaScript( "http://host.com/file1.js", "file2.js")}` annotation. [Vaadin+Javascript](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating+a+JavaScript+component)

Comment: Yes I did all that. The problem is that I don't want the js files to be loaded unless the browser is IE8. So I want to control the entire HTML template so I can add or modify anything in the "head" of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution but I think it's not a good practice :

First create a js file. 
file.js :

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
 $('head').append('<!--[if lt IE 9]>'
          +'<script src=\"https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js\"> </script>'
          +'<script src=\"https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js\"></script>'
          +'<![endif]-->');
 });
```

In your Vaadin Application you can add :

```
@JavaScript({ "vaadin://themes/YourTheme/js/file.js"})
```

It worked but not as I expected. It can help you in some cases but not if you want to detect the browser before that vaadin generate the HTML.