# adding a facebook pixel to vaadin application

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am new to vaadin and know just a little about html and javascript , but I know preety well pure java.

I am working on my web application and I need a way to add a facebook pixel to the application. to those of you who are not familiar with this term , it is just a piece of code that needs to be inserted between the head tags on the html.

just like the google analytics pixel only that I have found an addon for google analytics but not for facebook .

I'd appriciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your own [SessionInitListener](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.6/com/vaadin/server/SessionInitListener.html) in the `VaadinServlet` and during the [sessionInit](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.6/com/vaadin/server/SessionInitListener.html#sessionInit%28com.vaadin.server.SessionInitEvent%29) method call you need to add [bootstrapListener](https://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.rc2/docs/api/com/vaadin/server/BootstrapListener.html) with a `modifyBootstrapPage` method

Example can be found here: [How to change default HTML template in Vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906840/how-to-change-default-html-template-in-vaadin)